# print encoded huffman character

Tags: c#, encode, huffman-code

I have written a program to compress an image using huffman algorithm , it first Converts Image to a base64 string and then proceeds with building the tree and encoding the characters.Now I want to add a part to my program in order to print out a character and it's huffman code.(It is already printing a fake huffman code for each character :D ). 
here is my program classes codes :

Program.cs :

```html
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Collections;

namespace HuffmanTest
{
    class Program
    {
        public static string ImageToBase64(Image image,
  System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat format)
        {
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                // Convert Image to byte[]
                image.Save(ms, format);
                byte[] imageBytes = ms.ToArray();

                // Convert byte[] to Base64 String
                string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
                return base64String;
            }
        }
        public static Image Base64ToImage(string base64String)
        {
            // Convert Base64 String to byte[]
            byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0,
              imageBytes.Length);

            // Convert byte[] to Image
            ms.Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
            Image image = Image.FromStream(ms, true);
            return image;
        }
 
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome, The Operation Has Begun.");
            var img = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(@"E:\gray.bmp");
            string input = ImageToBase64(img, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
            HuffmanTree huffmanTree = new HuffmanTree();

            // Build the Huffman tree
            huffmanTree.Build(input);

            // Encode
            BitArray encoded = huffmanTree.Encode(input);
            Console.WriteLine("Encoded: ");
            foreach (bool bit in encoded)
            {
                Console.Write((bit ? 1 : 0) + "");
            }
            Console.Beep();
            Console.WriteLine();

            // Decode
            string decoded = huffmanTree.Decode(encoded);

           Console.WriteLine("Decoded: ");
            Console.WriteLine(decoded);
            Console.Beep();
            Image fout = Base64ToImage(decoded);
            fout.Save("E:\\myImage.bmp", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
            Console.WriteLine("Image Saved Sucuessfully.");
            char[] s = input.ToCharArray();
            int cratio = encoded.Length / s.Length;
            Console.WriteLine("Compression Ratio is {0}%", cratio);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Node.cs

```html
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace HuffmanTest
{
    public class Node
    {
        public char Symbol { get; set; }
        public int Frequency { get; set; }
        public Node Right { get; set; }
        public Node Left { get; set; }

        public List<bool> Traverse(char symbol, List<bool> data)
        {
            // Leaf
            if (Right == null && Left == null)
            {
                if (symbol.Equals(this.Symbol))
                {
                    return data;
                }
                else
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                List<bool> left = null;
                List<bool> right = null;

                if (Left != null)
                {
                    List<bool> leftPath = new List<bool>();
                    leftPath.AddRange(data);
                    leftPath.Add(false);

                    left = Left.Traverse(symbol, leftPath);
                }

                if (Right != null)
                {
                    List<bool> rightPath = new List<bool>();
                    rightPath.AddRange(data);
                    rightPath.Add(true);
                    right = Right.Traverse(symbol, rightPath);
                }

                if (left != null)
                {
                    return left;
                }
                else
                {
                    return right;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

HuffmanTree.cs :

```html
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections;

namespace HuffmanTest
{
    public class HuffmanTree
    {
        private List<Node> nodes = new List<Node>();
        public Node Root { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<char, int> Frequencies = new Dictionary<char, int>();

        public void Build(string source)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; i++)
            {
                if (!Frequencies.ContainsKey(source[i]))
                {
                    Frequencies.Add(source[i], 0);
                }

                Frequencies[source[i]]++;
            }

            foreach (KeyValuePair<char, int> symbol in Frequencies)
            {
                nodes.Add(new Node() { Symbol = symbol.Key, Frequency = symbol.Value });
                Console.WriteLine("Symbol          Frequency");
                Console.WriteLine("{0}                {1}          {2}", symbol.Key,Math.Abs(Frequencies.Values.Max()- symbol.Value)+1,Convert.ToString(symbol.Value,2));
            }

            while (nodes.Count > 1)
            {
                List<Node> orderedNodes = nodes.OrderBy(node => node.Frequency).ToList<Node>();
                
                if (orderedNodes.Count >= 2)
                {
                    // Take first two items
                    List<Node> taken = orderedNodes.Take(2).ToList<Node>();

                    // Create a parent node by combining the frequencies
                    Node parent = new Node()
                    {
                        Symbol = '*',
                        Frequency = taken[0].Frequency + taken[1].Frequency,
                        Left = taken[0],
                        Right = taken[1]
                    };

                    nodes.Remove(taken[0]);
                    nodes.Remove(taken[1]);
                    nodes.Add(parent);
                }

                this.Root = nodes.FirstOrDefault();

            }

        }

        public BitArray Encode(string source)
        {
            List<bool> encodedSource = new List<bool>();

            for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; i++)
            {
                List<bool> encodedSymbol = this.Root.Traverse(source[i], new List<bool>());
                encodedSource.AddRange(encodedSymbol);
            }

            BitArray bits = new BitArray(encodedSource.ToArray());

            return bits;
        }

        public string Decode(BitArray bits)
        {
            Node current = this.Root;
            string decoded = "";

            foreach (bool bit in bits)
            {
                if (bit)
                {
                    if (current.Right != null)
                    {
                        current = current.Right;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (current.Left != null)
                    {
                        current = current.Left;
                    }
                }

                if (IsLeaf(current))
                {
                    decoded += current.Symbol;
                    current = this.Root;
                }
            }

            return decoded;
        }

        public bool IsLeaf(Node node)
        {
            return (node.Left == null && node.Right == null);
        }

    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is preventing you from printing the character and its huffman code?

Comment: What's stopping you from printing it?  You have all that code, yet you can't write some text to the console?

Comment: @Amy I can print out the encoded version of string,but i can't figure out how to print it out character to character with their huffman code.

Comment: @itsme86 just what I told Amy.